# Is it OK to refresh Expiration Date every time to send notification ?

Tags: azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

Since a registration's expiration time is 90 Days.

So I plan to check first for every concern devices/registration before sending any notification.
Because I don't want to keep anything on server.

However, I'm not sure if it's good idea to do 
Is it slow to do for lots devices ?

Also, I can not find a way to set Expiration time of any registration 
So I've never seen result when sending to expired device ?

Can anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

the common recommended approach is to refresh registration on every app start-up per documented at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-registration-management/. This ensures that Notification Hubs holds the most recent token provided by the device PNS.

Comment: Yes, we have the process to refresh registration on every app start-up

But if the application still be logged in (background mode) over 90 days 
The application won't get any notification.
That's why I have to check every time before sending if the target registration is still valid

Comment: Just a quick note, since juni, the document states:

"It is important to note that registrations and installations by default no longer expire."

I assume that this makes the expire field confusing, but not a problem anymore.